# Stochastic Differential Equation with drift multiplied by everywhere discontinuous random process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

(WARNING: this has been crossposted on physics.stackexchange (questions/588606). It has been suggested to post also here, let me know if it is against the rules).

Let the stochastic process $\{X_t\}$ be defined by the following SDE (Ito's convention for discretization)

$dX_t=\frac{1}{p}S_tg(X_t)dt+\sqrt{2}dW_t$

where $W_t$ is a standard Wiener process, $g: \mathrm{R}\rightarrow \mathrm{R}$ is a $C^{\infty}$ function and $S_t$ is an other (white) stochastic process described by

\begin{align}
&P_{rob}(S_t=1)=p,\quad P_{rob}(S_t=0)=1-p\\
& S_t\perp S_\tau, \quad \forall t\neq\tau
\end{align}
where $p\in(0,1]$

Informally you could think of $S_t$ as a (sort of) telegraph process https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegraph_process

My questions are the following:

1. Does it make sense to define a process like $S_t$?
2. If 1) has positive answer, can I use the infinitesimal generator formalism (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal_generator_(stochastic_processes)) to derive, for example the Fokker Planck equations for the process $X_t$?

For completeness, the definition of infinitesimal generator $\mathcal{A}$
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{A}h(\mathbf{x})=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{E(h(X_t)|X_0=x)-h(x)}{t}
\end{equation}
where $h()$ is a suitable function $\mathrm{R}\rightarrow \mathrm{R}$

Forgive me for being formally imprecise, I am not trained in pure math but I do use SDEs simulation schemes for engineering/physics problems.

Comment: Assuming $p\ne 1,$ create successive simulations of $X_t$ in any interval where $g$ is nonzero, taking smaller and smaller steps in time for each simulation.  Notice what happens to the variance of $X_t$ at the end of that interval: that should answer your question.

Comment: thanks. the simulation part is not bothering me. the point is that if I blindly apply the definition of infinitesimal generator the resulting generator is the same that we have for classical diffusion, indepentently from $p$. I am worried that such kind of process is not valid for the usage of the infinitesimal generator. I am mainly looking for a theoretical reason why what I am doing makes no sense (something on the lines: $S_t$ is everywhere discontinuous, the theory does not hold)

Comment: The simulation ought to convince you that this equation has no solution and will indicate what the theoretical reason is (namely, the total variation of the $S_tg(t)$ term is infinite in any finite interval).

Comment: thanks again. Just to be sure, the similation scheme I am using is the folowing: after initialization $X[0]=x_0$, the random process is updated according to 

$X[n+1]=X[n]+S[n]g(X[n])\eta+\sqrt{2\eta}W[n]$

where $S[n]$ is extracted according to $p(S[n]=1)=p,p(S[n]=0)=1-p$ and $W[n]\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $\eta\rightarrow0$. 
Are you suggesting that as $\eta\rightarrow0$ the solution should not exists?

Comment: As $\eta\to0$ the solution diverges for all $t\gt 0.$  BTW, it's difficult to read your equations because your symbol "$p$" appears to be overloaded. I have understood $S_t$ to be a Bernoulli$(p)$ variable for all $t.$

Comment: @ernst With the time step $\eta \to 0$ my intuition tells me that the noise term $S_t$ becomes irrelevant and the equation becomes equivalent to  $$dX_t=g(X_t)dt+\sqrt{2}dW_t$$ Does the physics that this model relate to also have the situation $\eta \to 0$?

Comment: The intuition is that for a certain small time step $\Delta t$, the total drift in that time step can be approximated by a discrete sum $$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{p} S_{t + \frac{k}{n} \Delta t} g(X_{t +\frac{k}{n} \Delta t}) \frac{\Delta t}{n}$$ And since $ g(X_{t +\frac{k}{n} \Delta t} )$ is more or less constant over a small time step $\Delta t$ this becomes approximately $$ g(X_{t})  \Delta t  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{p} S_{t + \frac{k}{n} \Delta t} $$ where the sum will approach 1 when $n \to \infty$

Comment: So it boils down to the meaning of $\int_a^b S_t dt$. If find this a strange term. Do you evaluate $S_t$ for infinitesimally small steps, then there are infinitesimally many additions of $S_t$ and the increase will approach the mean of $S_t$ (by the law of large numbers)

Comment: Is $S_t$ supposed to be a telegraph process? Then $S_t$ and $S_\tau$ are not independent.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus yes, my intuition (actually also the calculations I made) tells me that the process $S_t$ is irrelevant (sort of self-averaging). $S_t$ is not supposed to be a telegraph process, it was just the closest analogy I could find. As stated $S_t\perp S_\tau,\quad t\neq \tau$. Do you have any theoretical reference for stating that the process $S_t$ is indeed well defined and makes sense from a formal point of view?

Comment: You could view your $S_t$ as a telegraph process in which the transition rates go to infinity (such that the correlation/dependence approaches zero). Do you really have complete independence, even for the closest possible time difference?